Chainlink Functions call fails when cost estimation is way over the actual cost or computation failed to fetch DONHosted secrets: not found
I'm facing some odd behaviour when call my function in Ethereum/Sepolia. First if estimation cost is bigger than my actual funds the call fails (even though the final cost is way less than the estimation, here is an example: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xef7df76cc8e04957bedab45bc8f9923e45b6171acf8d5335fafac52b4061b149). For transaction above, sdk estimation was: 21.898907103915263498 LINK (using subscriptionManager.estimateFunctionsRequestCost), then chainlink function's dashboard shows ~24.41 LINK (when transaction is still pending) finally the real cost was 1.18 LINK.
The other thing is that sometimes my function fails with error: failed to fetch DONHosted secrets: not found. This happens for transactions way overestimated or other closer to final cost (estimation ~3.65 LINK).
Code for getting DON hosted secret version is an API and don't know if calling SecretsManager#initialize and/or SubscriptionManager#initialize multiple times or using always slotIdNumber = 0 may have something to do with the aforementioned error: failed to fetch DONHosted secrets: not found. Here is my code:
  await subscriptionManager.initialize();
  await secretsManager.initialize();
  const gasPriceWei = (await signer.getGasPrice()).toBigInt();
  const secrets = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
  };

  const gatewayUrls = [
    "https://01.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/",
    "https://02.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/"
  ];
  const slotIdNumber = 0;
  const expirationTimeMinutes = 15;
  const gasLimit = 300000;

  //////// ESTIMATE REQUEST COSTS ////////

  console.log("\nEstimate function request costs...");

  const estimatedCostInJuels = await subscriptionManager.estimateFunctionsRequestCost({
    donId: donId,
    subscriptionId: subscriptionId,
    callbackGasLimit: gasLimit,
    gasPriceWei: gasPriceWei,
  });

  console.log(`Fulfillment function cost estimated to ${ethers.utils.formatEther(estimatedCostInJuels)} LINK`);

  console.log("\nMake request...");
  const encryptedSecretsObj = await secretsManager.encryptSecrets(secrets);
  const uploadResult = await secretsManager.uploadEncryptedSecretsToDON({
    encryptedSecretsHexstring: encryptedSecretsObj.encryptedSecrets,
    gatewayUrls: gatewayUrls,
    slotId: slotIdNumber,
    minutesUntilExpiration: expirationTimeMinutes,
  });


On-chain code is using both slotId and uploadResult.version to call chainlink function:
FunctionsRequest.Request memory req;
        req.initializeRequestForInlineJavaScript(source);
        if (donHostedSecretsVersion > 0) {
            req.addDONHostedSecrets(
                donHostedSecretsSlotID, // this is slotId
                donHostedSecretsVersion // this is uploadResult.version
            );
        }
        if (args.length > 0) req.setArgs(args);
        requestId = _sendRequest(
            req.encodeCBOR(),
            subscriptionId,
            gasLimit,
            donID
        );

Note: gasLimit is fixed to: 300000

That is weird, do you still have the same issue if you increase the balance to like 30 LINKs? Because the estimated gas limit sometimes is not accurate, it is different from chain to chain. It is also influenced by Link price. I suggest you can add a little bit more in balance than the estimate cost.

@FrankKong I did increase balance to ~50 LINK and it solve the issue, I just didn't expect an overestimation so high, neither it'll make the request to fail

When you submitted a new request, gaslimit is a argument. The cost will be calculated by gas limit you input. If you don't need a very high gas limit, lower it down and it might help you.
